# Disagreement between BigQuery and Google Analytics 4 for Pageviews - why?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I have a large table of Google Analytics 4 (GA4) events in Big Query for a bunch of websites I look after. The table has the following schema:

| field name | type |
| --- | --- |
| event_date | date |
| event_timestamp | integer |
| event_name | string |
| event_key | string |
| event_string_value | string |
| event_int_value | integer |
| event_float_value | float |
| event_double_value | float |
| user_pseudo_id | string |
| user_first_touch_timestamp | integer |
| device_category | string |
| device_model_name | string |
| device_host_name | string |
| device_web_hostman | string |
| geo_country | string |
| geo_city | string |
| traffic_source_name | string |

I query the table to get the total number for pageviews for a specific site using the following query:

```
with date_range as (
select
    '20220601' as start_date,
    '20220630' as end_date)

select
    count(distinct case when event_name = 'page_view' then concat(user_pseudo_id, cast(event_timestamp as string)) end) as pageviews

from
    `project_name.datset_name.table_name`,
    date_range
WHERE
    event_date BETWEEN PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d',date_range.start_date) AND PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d',date_range.end_date)
AND device_web_hostname in ("www.website_name.com")
```

What is a mystery to me is that when I do this for some sites, the figure for page_views is out by several hundred pageviews. The Big Query figure is higher. What is interesting is that:

- If I try other events, such as sessions then there are no issues
- As stated, it is only for some sites and not all

I know enought to know:

- These numbers are never going to agree, but they shouldn't be out by several hundred either
- GA4 has the unprocessed data, so the way I am querying the data is different to how it is being processed in the GA4 interface

I have tried:

- Looking at the GA4 documentation to see how pageviews are used/processed; I can't see anything that enlightens me
- Debugging each site to make sure tags are firing correctly; they are

I've hit a bit of a wall with this and I'd begrateful if anyone has any insight to point me in another possible direction. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in this following part of the code:

```
select
    count(distinct case when event_name = 'page_view' then concat(user_pseudo_id, cast(event_timestamp as string)) end) as pageviews
```

You are counting distinct for concat of user_pseudo_id and event_timestamp which is not unique. You need to also have session_id on top of that to get a unique hit.